# Three column layout image should be in center in two resolution (1024 by 768 & 1366 by 768)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have searched for my question in stack overflow. I have got answers. But the answers is not enough for the current question.

Here is the code

```
<div id="firstdiv">
        Testing 1
    </div>
    <div id="middlediv">
        <img src="image/testing.png" width="950px" height="150px"/>
    </div>
    <div id="lastdiv">
        Testing 2
    </div>
```

Here is the css

```
#firstdiv
    {   
        width:20%;
        position:absolute;
        border:1px solid DarkGrey;
        float:left;
    }
    #middlediv
    {
        width:60%;
        border:1px solid Blue;          
        margin-left:21%;
    }
    #lastdiv
    {
        width:20%;
        border:1px solid red;
        position:absolute;
        float:right;
    }
```

My Question

I need three column layout first column should be in left in middle the image and last column should be in right  (In all resolution).

Note : I don't want to use RWD method.

Kindly help me for the above question.

If you have not understand question kindly reply. please don't block my account.

Thanks & Regards
Mahadevan

Comment: What have you tried so far? And how was that (and your previous answers) inadequate)

Comment: Hi @TylerH I have tried using above code. But it was not at all working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/BrYbJ/

html:

```
<div class="box">
    <div id="firstdiv">Testing 1</div><!--
    --><div id="middlediv"><img src="image/testing.png" width="950px" height="150px"/></div><!--
    --><div id="lastdiv">Testing 2</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.box {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.box div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}

#firstdiv
{   
    width:20%;
    outline:1px solid DarkGrey;
}
#middlediv
{
    width:60%;
    outline:1px solid Blue;         
    position:relative;
}
#middlediv img {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#firstdiv
{   
    width:20%;
    outline:1px solid DarkGrey;
    float:left;
}
#middlediv
{
    width:60%;
    outline:1px solid Blue;         
    float:left;
}
#lastdiv
{
    width:20%;
    outline:1px solid red;
    float:left;
}
```

This should do the trick

Comment: Hi 

Your trick partially worked but when i reduced the screen resolution. The image is not in center. And the other divs are not properly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `position: absolute`, cou could try using `display: inline-block` and removing the html whitespace:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wm4wm/)

html:

```
<div id="firstdiv">Testing 1</div><div id="middlediv"><img src="image/testing.png" /></div><div id="lastdiv">Testing 2</div>
```

css:

```
#firstdiv {
    width:20%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#middlediv {
    width:60%;
    display: inline-block;
}
#lastdiv {
    width:20%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Keep in mind, that if you do not use `border-box`, then using borders affects the size of an element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But when i put the same code it was not coming properly